# Selected value from select html tag not producing correct result in javascript if/else statement

Tags: javascript, html

** Edited: Thank you for your initial responses! After going through to build on my initial code I am at another roadblock. I am trying to allow the 'change' for all my selectors, but now it will update in my JS. Also, prior to adding the doStuff(document.querySelectorAll()); I was using document.getElementById().addEventListener('change'), which was allowing my if/else statement to run, but when trying to write it to the page it deleted out my html. I do not want that to happen as I would like it to either show after I run the function at the bottom if I want to update a selector or auto update as I go down and update my selectors. Once again I am grateful for the help.

I am new to coding so this my not be the prettiest code, but I am trying to learn.

My HTML code is as follows:

```
    <body>
  <form method="POST">
    <div id="dynamicInput1">
      <ul>
        <strong>Is the individual/entire family under 30?</strong>
      </ul>
      <select id="myDropDown1">
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="dynamicInput2">
      <ul><strong>High utilizer of Healthcare? Examples:</strong>
        <li>Takes prescription drugs</li>
        <li>Goes to the doctor or specialist frequently</li>
        <li>Managing a chronic condition</li>
        <li>Or having a planned procedure</li>
      </ul>
      <select id="myDropDown2">
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

My JavaScript is as follows:

```
    doStuff(document.querySelectorAll('myDropDown1, myDropDown2').addEventListener('change', function() {
  var dropDown1 = document.getElementById('myDropDown1').value;
  var dropDown2 = document.getElementById('myDropDown2').value;

  if(dropDown1 === 'yes') {
    alert('Holy Crap!')
  } else if(dropDown2 === 'no') {
    alert('Is this going to work?')
  } else{
    alert('WTF...')
  };
}));
```

Comment: In what function do you have the javascript code? Could you provide a js fiddle?

Comment: How do you call your code? Is it in a function?

Comment: js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/69n9xq5o/ 

I am currently not calling it as I am just running it in codepen and js fiddler. I am looking to add a submit button at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you're defining your `dropDown1` variable only once (maybe outside the callback function you pass to the event handler), and then it will never get updated.

If you define it inside the listener,  it will work, since it will be updated with the new value. Look below:

```js
document.getElementById('myDropDown1').addEventListener('change', function() {
  var dropDown1 = document.getElementById("myDropDown1").value;
  var dropDown2 = document.getElementById("myDropDown2").value;

  if (dropDown1 === "yes") {
    alert("Holy Crap!");
  } else {
    alert("WTF...");
  };
});
```

```html
<body>
  <form method="POST">
    <div id="dynamicInput1">
      <ul><strong>Is the individual/entire family under 30?</strong>
      </ul>
      <select id="myDropDown1">
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="dynamicInput2">
      <ul><strong> High utilizer of Healthcare? Examples:</strong> 
        <li>Takes prescription drugs</li>
        <li>Goes to the doctor or specialist frequently</li>
        <li>Managing a chronic condition</li>
        <li>Or have a planned procedure</li>
      </ul>
      <br>
      <select id="myDropDown2">
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an on change event to your select element:

```
<select id="myDropDown1" onchange="myFunction()">
```

Then define the function being called

```
function myFunction() {
  var dropDown1 = document.getElementById("myDropDown1").value;

  var dropDown2 = document.getElementById("myDropDown2").value;

  if (dropDown1 === "yes") {
        alert("Holy Crap!");
  } else {
       alert("WTF...");
  };
}
```

One problem this way is you have to set an on change event for each select element in your html. If using JQuery:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    //Do event with $this
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

**1)** Add `onchange` function calls to your both drop-down selects. Along with retrieving the value during select.

**2)** Add two functions for both the drop-down's in your JavaScript.

[Working : Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eryoc75v/)

```js
function dropdown1(val1) {
    if (val1 == "yes") {
        alert("Holy Crap!");
    } else {
        alert("WTF...");
    }
}

function dropdown2(val2) {
    if (val2 == "yes") {
        alert("Holy Crap!");
    } else {
        alert("WTF...");
    }
}
```

```html
<form method="POST">
    <div id="dynamicInput1">
        <ul><strong>Is the individual/entire family under 30?</strong>

        </ul>
        <select id="myDropDown1" onchange="dropdown1(this.value)">
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="dynamicInput2">
        <ul><strong> High utilizer of Healthcare? Examples:</strong> 
            <li>Takes prescription drugs</li>
            <li>Goes to the doctor or specialist frequently</li>
            <li>Managing a chronic condition</li>
            <li>Or have a planned procedure</li>
            <ul>
                <br>
                <select id="myDropDown2" onchange="dropdown2(this.value)">
                    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="no">No</option>
                </select>
    </div>
</form>
```